# Identify this movie with some stupid guy robbing his regular shop

Tags: identify-this-movie

I recently remembered a scene from a movie but can't quite place it. To give my racing mind some peace, would you please try to identify this movie?

So, some guy, about 18 to 25 years old, hangs around some kind of general store on a regular basis and becomes (or is) good friends with the store owner who maybe plays some kind of fatherly role. The boy's not really clever and somehow manages to need quite an amount of money. Maybe he owes the mob, I don't know. Anyway, he decides to rob the store he used to hang around in but the store owner (male? female?) instantly recognizes him and fights him off.

One thing I can remember is, that the store owner, while fighting the perp off, shouts something like "why are you so stupid? You stupid stupid boy!". They don't seem to be too angry about the attempted robbery itself but just disappointed in the guy and maybe the broken trust.

I believe it to be an English language movie, but it might be German, in which case I want to apologize.

Based on the roadmovie-ish feel I have about that movie I'd place it between 1995 and 2005 but don't pin me down for it. Also, note that this scene is by far not the main "thing" in that movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there was a scene like this in [White Men Can't Jump](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105812/). There were a lot of secondary basketball players in various scenes of that movie.  One of them needed money to place a bet, so he put a stocking over his head (I think?) and ran into a store where the owner recognized him immediately, told him he knew him from when he was a kid, and kicked him out of the store.

Might be a totally different movie than what you're thinking of.  But I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: It's like ages ago since I watched that movie. I'll try to verify if this is the one.

Comment: I wish I knew where it occurred in the movie, but I just remember it's not in the beginning, and it's not at the end.  I think it's somewhere around 45 minutes in.  (But I could be completely wrong.) Keep your ears open in the first ten minutes for one of my favorite movie lines, which I still quote:  "I don't mean to brag, but I'm the greatest!!" Ahh, Wesley Snipes.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of this exact same scene.  The guy needed money to bet on a game he was playing against Snipes and Harrelson.  But it doesn't fit the exact description of the OP's question.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, I just verified it. Seems I was reading way too much into the scene. Good catch :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for finally checking this out. (Wow, did I post my answer in February??? I remember it so clearly...!)

Answer (score 1):

Any chance that it was Thai and not German? I'm pretty sure there was a similar scene in Tony Jaa's [*The Protector (Tom yum goong)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0427954/), in which someone attempts to rob a store while wearing a stocking over his head, but the shop owner berates him for being easily recognisable. Unfortunately I can't find any clips of it anywhere online...

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Movies and TV Stack Exchange! Thank you for your answer - hopefully the Original Poster (OP) will be able to get back to you and confirm/deny it. In the meantime, do you have any screens from the movie you could share to help the OP? Additionally, please take a Tour of the site under the Help menu at the top of the screen to get some more information on how the site works and what sort of questions are asked here.

Comment: @Dre - The full movie, split into five parts, is available [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/user/Srey_Leap/15) for your reference. Appears to be a dub, but it should do the trick :-)